# Convert bytes to bitmap

Tags: java, android, arrays, tcp, bitmap

I am trying to send an image through a socket from a server to a client. I converted the bitmap image into an array of bytes and sent the array to the client. But now I am having issues converting the array bytes back into bitmap on my client. Right now my bitmap print statement tells me that my bitmap value is "null". Does anyone know how I can fix this so I can save my bitmap image as a png on my client?

My client code, which receives the image as bytes in an array

```
try {

          System.out.println("TRY");

          Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.26", 5050);

          // Get data sent through socket
          DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

          System.out.println("DataInputStream Started");

          // read data that got sent
          String msg_received = DIS.readUTF();
          System.out.println("Message from server" + msg_received);

          String PACKAGENAME = DIS.readUTF();
          System.out.println("Message from server" + PACKAGENAME);

          // read array data for bitmap

          byte[] data;//String read = input.readLine();
          int len= DIS.readInt();
          data = new byte[len];
          if (len > 0) {
             DIS.readFully(data,0,data.length);
          }


          bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length);




          socket.close();


       } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Did not receive string");
       }
```

Comment: Is `len` correct? `data` has data in it?

Comment: Are you sending the length before sending the bitmap on the client side?

Comment: @dharms I updated my question because I realized I made a mistake that my server is sending the image to my client, after my client makes the connection to the server. But anyway, my server is sending the array of bytes and the length in the same bundle. "len", on my client code, is the integer length that is getting passed from the server.

Comment: maybe you re in the same class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875060/how-to-convert-bytes-to-bitmap-to-png-for-image-sent-through-socket

Comment: @AlLelopath Here is my output for len (length), data (byte array) and bitmap: 

length = 36864
data = [B@22e294e8
Bitmap = null

Comment: Does `len == data.length` (and not 0)?

Comment: @AlLelopath len is my variable length (sorry for the confusion), so in my previous comment, len == 36864, which I presume to be data.length.

Comment: I wouldn't presume, I would check to be sure.

Comment: Looking around the web, I [see here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/datainputstream_readfully.htm) they use a call to `DataInputStream.available()`. You might try that.

Comment: @AlLelopath It looks like they are using DIS.available() only for extracting the length. I checked, and the length of the array that I am sending over, is the same length that I am receiving. I can update my question to show what I am sending if that is part of the issue... but also the array of bytes for my image that I am sending is [B@4208bfc0, and the data that I am receiving is [B@22e26158. Should these printed values be the same? Or it's okay that they are not?

Comment: Its fine that the addresses of the sending and receiving objects are different. As a debug step, I would use a for loop to read through bytes one at a time, to see what you're getting back. (`readFully()` will be faster executing, so you'll ultimately want to use that. This is just a debug thing)

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I used this code to print out my values of my array before I send them, and when I receive them. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/UsewhilelooptoreadaByteBuffer.htm My Android Monitor does not print every value (I guess because there are so many coming in so fast. But for the values I can compare it looks like all the byte values are the same that are getting sent and received. So, for some reason there is a problem with this line:   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length);